# C# linq query to filter out only items of a specified type, that meet a specified condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection that can contain different types. If the object is of type 'A', I just want to return that object, however if the object is of type 'B', then I want to return it only if it meets a certain condition (the condition will be invalid for type A and so will throw an exception if I try to check it). Something like:

```
model.MyList = model.MyList.Where(d => d.GetType().Equals(typeof(MyTypeB)) ? !d.IsSomeCondition: d );
```

Comment: Are type A and type B inherit the same class or interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just return true

```
d => d.GetType().Equals(typeof(MyTypeB)) ? !d.IsSomeCondition: true
```

where is just filtering so only needs a true or false response.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
.Where(d => d is MyTypeA || (d is MyTypeB && !(d as MyTypeB).IsSomeCondition)));
```